# Add a separator in the Windows Explorer context menu (not in a submenu)

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu

I have found that "CommandFlags"=dword:00000040 will add a separator below an entry, though only to a submenu (under the "subcommands"="" string). Example [here](https://blog.sverrirs.com/2014/05/creating-cascading-menu-items-in.html).

Is there a way to add a separator in the main context menu?

The example I am using:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\Delete With Rimraf]
@="Delete With Rimraf"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000040
```

This gives no separator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This example feature a separator after and before the item, this entry is for VirusTotal Uploader

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\vtuploader]
@="Send to VirusTotal"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\VirusTotalUploader2\\VirusTotalUploader2.2.exe,0"
"SeparatorBefore"=""
"SeparatorAfter"=""
```

For other applications loaded over shellex it's not possible to add separator over registry, the injected dll add/remove separator itself, you need then to change the dll code and recompile it to achieve what you want here is an example with notepad++ 
https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/pull/3092/commits

```
InsertMenu(hMenu, nIndex, MF_STRING | MF_BYPOSITION, idCmd++, m_szMenuTitle);
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi I'm the author of the blog entry you refer to (https://blog.sverrirs.com/2014/05/creating-cascading-menu-items-in.html)

Your options to manipulate the main context menu are quite restricted. The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx#cascading_extended) indicates that you might only be able to use the `ECF_SEPARATORBEFORE (0x20)` value for top-level items.